# CAN you directly install a hyundai coupe v6 engine in a hyundai coupe that had a 4 cylinder?

Tags: engine, hyundai, part-interchange, tuscani

I have a 2006 Hyundai Tuscani(aka tiburon) coupe(4 cylinder 2l).  The engine is not working and needs to be replaced.  Can I get the engine from the Hyundai coupe 2.7l v6 and directly install it into my car?

Comment: Is the V6 out of another Tuscani (aka: Tiburon)? Would it be *just the engine* or would you get other parts of it as well? At a minimum, besides the engine, you'd need the wiring harness and ECU out of the V6 Tuscani. More than likely you'd also need the k-member (the part which the engine sits on and the front suspension attaches to). Plus you'd also need the exhaust from a donor as well.

Comment: I don't have access to the v6 car.  At the moment I was just searching to buy the engine by itself assuming that's all I needed.  But seems it's not as simple as that.

Comment: whenever you change your engine with something bigger you must also consider extra costs as yours car was not designed for that bigger engine, like you might need to adjust suspensions to compensate the added weight of the engine. It is not as easy as it sounds like :)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 in the first instance would it fit inside the engine bay to begin with?  based on the pictures, it seems the v6 is vertically positioned whereas the 4 cylinder is horizontally positioned.

Comment: The Tiburon/Tuscani come with both the V6 and the 4-cyl engines from the factory. Since there is a factory option for either, then a 6-cyl engine would fit in the engine bay of your vehicle. The question is the amount of work and parts it would take to get it there. The *easiest* way to get it into your vehicle is to have a donor vehicle which would have all the parts in one place to make it happen. If a donor is not available, that leaves you to piecing everything together to make it work. What I've mentioned above is only a smidge of what it's going to take you to make it happen.